# Vuforia Videoplayback issue - Video is playing inverted

Tags: android, android-studio, vuforia

Im working on a project combining Vuforia ImageTarget and VideoPlayback. I have 'N' number of targets and it have corresponding videos . For some imageTargets the video is flipped. I can't find any solution for this issue. Here is my VideoPlaybackRenderer

```
int videoPlaybackTextureID[] = new int[VideoPlayback.NUM_TARGETS];

// Keyframe and icon rendering specific
private int keyframeShaderID = 0;
private int keyframeVertexHandle = 0;
private int keyframeNormalHandle = 0;
private int keyframeTexCoordHandle = 0;
private int keyframeMVPMatrixHandle = 0;
private int keyframeTexSampler2DHandle = 0;

// We cannot use the default texture coordinates of the quad since these
// will change depending on the video itself
private float videoQuadTextureCoords[] =  { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, };


private Float videoQuadTextureCoordsTransformed[] =  {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,};


List<Float[]> videoQuadTextureCoordsTransformedList = new ArrayList<Float[]>();


// Trackable dimensions
Vec3F targetPositiveDimensions[] = new Vec3F[VideoPlayback.NUM_TARGETS];
```

Comment: What is the `Transform` rotation for each of the `ImageTarget`'s that you are using? What I mean is are they all set to (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: @Hristo sorry .. i didn't get you..!

Comment: When you are in Unity, and you select one of the `ImageTargets` from the _Hierarchy_ then look at the _Inspector_ tab, what are the values for the `Transform` **rotation**?

Comment: im using Android Studio

Comment: Then change your Tags..

Answer (score 4):

looks like you need to select the object video and then apply something like this:
example you select a cube.

this will rotate the cube 180 degrees without modifying any of the other rotational axis'

```
cube.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(cube.transform.rotation.x, cube.transform.rotation.y, cube.transform.rotation.z, 180);
```